# How do I add a new connection in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-365, microsoft365, microsoft-data-sqlclient

I have an existing Excel 365 file with multiple data connections.  I want to add a new connection, but I can't figure out how.  I can see the existing connections by clicking Data->Queries & Connections, but I can't figure out how to add a new one.  I can click on Data->Refresh All and see connections, but it's grayed out.  I tried going to Data->Get Data->From Database, but that creates a query not a connection.  I tried clicking on Data-> Existing Connections, but that just shows existing connections; there's no place to add one.
I've been using Excel for years so I hate to admit I can't figure this out, but would appreciate any assistance.

Here's the properties for an existing connection; I want to create a new connection like this (but with a different query/command text):

[image]

Here's what I see with the connections on the right side:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the legacy data connections.

- Go to File > Options > Data.
- Select the legacy data options you want to enable and hit OK.

[image]

Now go to the Data ribbon, click **Get Data > Legacy Wizards** and get your data the legacy way.

[image]

Comment: Wonderful.  Thank you!

Comment: @boilers222 with your rep you should know how to accept an answer, no?